# Create a specific role in a replicated AZURE SQL database, which is in read mode

Tags: azure-sql-database, user-roles

Can you give me some help with my Azure Sql, I am having a difficulty with assigning a new role to a database with "geo-redundancy".

**My current structure is:**

- **DB1** in zone_A replicated to another **DB2** (read only) in zone_B

**Drawback**

- I have a new user with new roles that were not replicated in my DB2, and I want to manually execute my statement without stopping my data replication. Could you help me solve if you had a similar problem?

**Script exec**

[image script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/651tp.png)

---

Msg 3906, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Failed to update **"DB2"** because the database is read-only.

Comment: are you try to update the data in a Secondary storage DB ?

Comment: Not the data, I only need to create a role that I had created in my BD1, because only the data is replicated but not the configuration